# Share repeated code blocks between roles

Tags: ansible, ansible-2.x

At beginning of most of my roles, there is the following code block. It tries to load os and version specific variables and tasks. Is it possible I don't repeat this piece of code for each of my role?

```
---

- name: Include OS specific variables.
  include_vars: "{{ item }}"
  with_first_found:
    - files:
      - "vars/{{ ansible_os_family }}.yml"
      skip: True

- name: Include distribution specific variables.
  include_vars: "{{ item }}"
  with_first_found:
    - files:
      - "vars/{{ ansible_distribution }}.yml"
      skip: True

- name: Include version specific variables.
  include_vars: "{{ item }}"
  with_first_found:
    - files:
      - "vars/{{ ansible_distribution }}{{ ansible_distribution_major_version }}.yml"
      skip: True

- name: Run OS specific preparation work.
  include: "{{ item }}"
  with_first_found:
    - files:
      - "tasks/{{ ansible_os_family }}.yml"
      skip: True

- name: Run distribution specific preparation work.
  include: "{{ item }}"
  with_first_found:
    - files:
      - "tasks/{{ ansible_distribution }}.yml"
      skip: True

- name: Run version specific preparation work.
  include: "{{ item }}"
  with_first_found:
    - files:
      - "tasks/{{ ansible_distribution }}{{ ansible_distribution_major_version }}.yml"
      skip: True
```

Answer (score 1):

Yes, you can use [include statements or even another role](https://docs.ansible.com/ansible/playbooks_roles.html) to pull in a task from an external, shared file.

Comment: My major concern is whether the lookup path is correct if I use include or another role. If I use another role, how does it look at `vars` directory of this role? Do you have any working examples?

Comment: You are right, roles will only look into adjacent directories when passed a relative path. But at a guess, if you go for the separate role ( which I suggest regardless ). You will have all those vars/tasks in that common role.